# DJANGO JSON filtering complicate key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to perform a DJANGO filtering logic on this JSON

```
"data": {
     "process":{
        "9123fd-b01-4a00-9arwefg":{
         "name":"PROCESS-1",
      }
   }
```

Here is currently what I can do:

```
object.filter(data__process={"9123fd-b01-4a00-9arwefg":{"name":"PROCESS-1"}}
```

But in reality, I can only input PROCESS-1 in my filtering input, so I want to do something like this

```
object.filter(data__process__9123fd-b01-4a00-9arwefg__name="PROCESS-1")
```

However, this is obviously not working because of the dash (-) in the key, is there anyway I can do the filtering with this complicate key?

Comment: Is the field you want to query on it a JSONField ?

Comment: Not entirely sure if it is a JSONField, I want query "PROCESS-1"